# How do I have a Python 3 program check if changing a variable's type would cause a crash before trying to change the type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I'm making a custom subroutine called userinput() in order to replace input().

1. I haven't tried anything as I have no clue what to try.
2. The program crashes when I try to convert the input from a string to an int/float if the input is not a number.
3. Here's the function:

   ```
   def userinput(text,valan,valtype):
       if valan == 0 and valtype == 0:
           a = input(text)
       elif valan == 0 and valtype != 0:
           val = 0
           while val == 0:
               a = input(text)
               if valtype == "int":
                   a = int(a)
               elif valtype == "float":
                   a = float(a)
               if type(a) != valtype:
                   print("Invalid answer.")
                   time.sleep(1)
                   print("Try again.")
                   time.sleep(1)
               else:
                   val = 1
       elif valan != 0 and valtype == 0:
           val = 0
           while val == 0:
               a = input(text)
               for i in range(0,len(valan)):
                   if valan[i] == a:
                       val = 1
               if val == 0:
                   print("Invalid answer.")
                   time.sleep(1)
                   print("Try again.")
                   time.sleep(1)
       return a
   ```

Comment: try refactoring your code by using `isinstance` function to check between numerical types or just `type` if user input is wrong (string, empty, none, etc)

Comment: What if neither argument is 0? You'll try to return the value of an undefined variable `a`.

Comment: What exactly is this function supposed to *do*? It can't seem to decide if `valtype` is supposed to be an integer (compares it to 0), a string (compares it to `"int"`) or a type (compares it to `type(a)`). Same for `valan`: you compare it to 0, but later assume it can be indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure i understood correctly what you are trying to archieve with your function but you can try to catch the exception (ValueError) that python throws when trying to cast your variable to a different datatype.

The problem here might be those instructions like `a = int(a)` or `a = float(a)`. You may try to replace them with:

```py
try:
    a = int(a)
except ValueError:
    print("Int conversion Failed")
```

and

```py
try:
    a = float(a)
except ValueError:
    print("Float conversion Failed")
```

Apart from that, it is not clear in your code for example if the `valtype` parameter should be an integer or a string (this may cause other errors). If you can give a more detailed explanation of your problem, maybe it's easier also for other people to get in touch with you for helping.

[Try/Catch documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) for further reading.